# Como votar em resposta meio certa e a influência da justificação

Tags: debate, votos

Quando uma resposta resolve uma questão, mas a sua explicação é equivocada e leva a um erro, deve-se negativar, ou usar o comentário como forma de alertar?

Fiz uso do comentário como alerta mas a culpa foi parar no IE6. (lol) Nem com a explicação quase ilustrada houve tentativa de reparar a resposta, isso me gerou a duvida - *negativar ou manter o comentário informativo*.

---

Outra dúvida que tenho é sobre a influência que os comentários justificando votos tem sobre as respostas. Se eu justifico posso estar influenciando apenas o interesse do usuário em *manter os pontos*, em contra partida, a falta de justificativa deixa por parte do AR o *interesse em questionar o voto e ajustar a resposta*.

Em ambos os casos eu apoio a justificativa, mas são casos diferentes que devem resultar em respostas de qualidade. Deve-se incentivar o interesse participativo do usuários, ou de imediato sanar qualquer equivoco nas repostas?

<sub>Não sei se fui claro o bastante no segundo item</sub>

Comment: Eu pessoalmente tentaria formular uma resposta melhor :)